# cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object

Tags: hibernate

```
try{
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria critSelectedResumes = session.createCriteria(SelectedResumes.class);
    critSelectedResumes.createAlias("resumeStatusId", "rsi");
    critSelectedResumes.add(Restrictions.eq("rsi.resumeStatusId", 2));
    Iterator ite;
    ite = critSelectedResumes.list().iterator();
    {
            while (it.hasNext()){
            Object[] pair = (Object[]) ite.next();
            SelectedResumes selectedResumes = (SelectedResumes)pair[0];
            ResumeStatus resumeStatus = (ResumeStatus) pair[1];
```

I am getting this error

```
SelectedResumes cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Any idea what could be the reason

Thanks

Comment: On which line is the error occurring?

Comment: Object[] pair = (Object[]) ite.next();          this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've created a `Criteria` object for the `SelectedResumes` class:

```
Criteria critSelectedResumes = session.createCriteria(SelectedResumes.class);
```

and then you call `list()` on it without specifying any projection, this method call will return a `java.util.List` of `SelectedResumes` objects. What you can do with this is either:

```
List<?> resultList1 = critSelectedResumes.list();
```

**or**

```
List<SelectedResumes> resultList2 
            = (List<SelectedResumes>)critSelectedResumes.list();
```

**or**

```
Iterator<SelectedResumes> iter =      
        (List<SelectedResumes>)critSelectedResumes.list().iterator();
```

Then you can go on to either

```
for(SelectedResumes selectedResumes:resultList2 ) {
      //do something with the SelectedResumes object
}
```

**or**

```
 while (it.hasNext()){
       SelectedResumes selectedResumes  = iter.next();
      //do something with the SelectedResumes object
 }
```

The `.list()` method of the [org.hibernate.Criteria](http://www.jdocs.com/hibernate/3.1.3/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) returns a `java.util.List` of whatever your query should return (usually beans or an array of projected key/value pairs - as in a List of arrays). It does not return an Array or anything else.

Comment: It's working cool. but what if i have more than one table and need to fetch data from both table than how criteria will work in this situation. Means how it will fetch and iterate data.

Answer (score 3):

You've set up a query to return a list of `SelectedResumes`:

```
Criteria critSelectedResumes = session
        .createCriteria(SelectedResumes.class);
```

and you're casting the list elements to `Object[]` (a.k.a. `[Ljava.lang.Object`):

```
Object[] pair = (Object[]) ite.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to cast a single object, selectedresumes, to an array.

I would change to this :

```
List<SelectedResumes> resumeList = critSelectedResumes.list();

for(SelectedResume selectedResume : resumeList){
...
//do stuff to  selectedResume
...
}
```